# Insert TableView cell with categories

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am developing and application that has a tableview, and I am able to insert new cells dynamically. The problem is that the tableview needs to have categories for something like color or shape, my question is:

When I am adding a new cell how can I choose in wish category the cell will be?

I know that I have to build my database in a certain way but the problem is that im no good with coredata and im a bit confused with the topic, so if someone could give me some explanation or sample code I would be very thankful.

Best Regards.

Comment: I am not getting point. Can you explain more or show image concerned?

Answer (score 1):

If you setup your datasource right, then you could retrieve an object with the desired category in it. When you retrieve that object in the `cellForRowAtIndexpath:` you will then extract that category and use it in some sort of switch statement which allows you to alter the cell with the desired shape and color and all you want.

For cleaner code however I suggest to make a custem cell and call some sort of update-method (in the same `cellforrowatindexpath:`) which does the same visual stuff for you.

What you do with the database or whatever should be seen apart from this matter since you should fetch that data in some other class. Which then will be shaped into your custom object which will then be put in your datasource.

Without some specifics in your question however this won't be more then theoretical shizzle.

However you should be able to figure this out.
Good luck.